# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int^x_1 t^{-1} \rho(t) dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt} = \rho$, where $\lim_{t \to \infty} \rho(t) = \rho \in (0,\infty)$

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory

I want to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int^x_1 t^{-1} \rho(t) dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt} = \rho$, where $\lim_{t \to \infty} \rho(t) = \rho \in (0,\infty)$ with $\rho \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$. It seems like dominated convergence theorem will not help here.

Here is the context:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What was your motivation for changing the notation after two answers appeared? It seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: @geetha290krm to match notation to the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any theorem. $|\frac{\int^x_N t^{-1} [\rho(t)-\rho] dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt}|\leq \epsilon$ if $N$ is chosen such that $|\rho(t)-\rho|<\epsilon$ for $t >N$. Now $|\frac{\int_1^N [\rho(t)-\rho] dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt}| \to 0$ because the numerator is bounded and the denominator, which is $x \ln x$, tends to $\infty$.

To finish the proof note that $\frac{\int^x_N t^{-1} [\rho(t)-\rho] dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt}=\frac{\int^x_N t^{-1} \rho(t) dt }{\int^x_1 t^{-1} dt}-\rho$.